# How to capture click on cross icon of jQuery dialog

Tags: jquery

I am using jQuery dialog and I need to capture the click event on cross icon of jQuery dialog because I want to do something.

```
$("#dialog").dialog({
              autoOpen: false,
              height: 430,
              width: 450,
              modal: false,
              draggable: false,
              resizable: false,
              zindex: 3999,
              close: function (ev, ui) {
                  //this function will be call back when dialog will be closed
              },
              show: {
                  effect: "fade",
                  duration: 1000
              },
              hide: {
                  effect: "fade",
                  duration: 500
              }

          });
```

Comment: that's exactly what you're doing http://jqueryui.it/demos/dialog#event-close

Comment: `.ui-dialog .ui-dialog-titlebar-close span` is the span for the close-x in the dialog. You could bind a click-event to `ui-icon-closethick`. At least, I think that would do.

Answer (score 0):

Why not

```
…

close: function (ev, ui) {
    $("body").trigger('dowhatyouwant');
},

…
```

And then

```
$("body").bind('dowhatyouwant', function() {
    doWhatIWant();
});
```

More info on [jQuery custom events](http://fuelyourcoding.com/jquery-custom-events-they-will-rock-your-world/).